# JMock matchers with setAttribute(String, Object)

Tags: java, junit, illegalargumentexception, matcher, jmock

I am facing issue while expecting a setAttribute call from a mock.

```
MyClass {
  public final void setAttribute(String name, Object value) {
  // Do Something
}

myClass.setAttribute("Key", "Value");
```

While invoking the setAttribute operation, String is passed as a value.
I have a mock of the above class by the name mockMyClass and in my Expectations block I have the below code.

```
oneOf(mockMyClass).setAttribute(with(equal("Key")), with(equal("Value")));
```

I have also tried using any, just to see if the generic works, but that is also giving the same issue.

Exception I am getting:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: not all parameters were given explicit matchers: either all parameters must be specified by matchers or all must be specified by values, you cannot mix matchers and values

Initially I was trying without any matchers and was getting the exception:

```
oneOf(mockMyClass).setAttribute("Key", "Value");
```

> org.jmock.api.ExpectationError: unexpected invocation

How to get this working? I intend to check for actual values.

Answer (score 1):

make method not final

```
 public void setAttribute(String name, Object value) {}
```

and use

```
oneOf(mockMyClass).setAttribute("Key", "Value");
```

or with matcher any();

from [jmock](http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html) --  **ClassImposteriser cannot create mocks of final classes or mock final methods.**

> Mocking Classes with jMock and the ClassImposteriser Because it uses
>   Java's standard reflection capability, the default configuration of
>   the jMock framework can only mock interfaces, not classes. (Actually,
>   we consider that to be a good thing because it encourages the design
>   to focus on communication between objects rather than static
>   classification or data storage). However, the ClassImposteriser
>   extension class uses the CGLIB 2.1 and Objenesis libraries to create
>   mock objects of classes as well as interfaces. This is useful when
>   working with legacy code to tease apart dependencies between tightly
>   coupled classes.
>
> The ClassImposteriser creates mock instances without calling the
>   constructor of the mocked class. So classes with constructors that
>   have arguments or call overideable methods of the object can be safely
>   mocked. However, the ClassImposteriser cannot create mocks of final
>   classes or mock final methods.
>
> If you want to mock final classes or final methods, the JDave library
>   includes an unfinalizer Instrumentation agent that can unfinalise
>   classes before they are loaded by the JVM. They can then be mocked by
>   the ClassImposteriser.